# How can I implement a list of values in WSO2 ESB Registry?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to implement a list of values (String) in a registry entrance. How can I make it?

And, Can I use fn:contains('','') to check if the value exists in registry?

Answer (score 0):

In Registry:

```
<list>
    <values>value1,value2,value3</values>
</list>
```

In API:

```
<property name="List" expression="get-property('registry','conf:/ListOfValue')" scope="default" type="OM"/>
<property name="values" expression=" expression="$ctx:List/values" scope="default" type="String"
```

And in values variable are string with values.